# Scrapy spider stats webservice JSON format

Tags: web-services, scrapy, scrapyd

How would one go about implementing a live feedback on what the spider is doing ? 
I have the logs that tell me each second pages per second and items, but i would like to access that via a webservice.

Maybe I'm wrong, but I found in the scrapy docs that there is something that should do this `http://localhost:6080/stats/spider_stats` but it returns empty.
Any ideas are welcome.

I would like to be able to do something like `curl http://localhost:6800/stats.json -d project=default -d spider=somespider`
and it would return `{"pages_crawled": "650","pages_per_min":"342","items_scraped":"286","items_per_min":"156"}`

Thanks,

Comment: This is pretty old but might help as a guide: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy-jsonrpc